# Identifying duplicate IDs using combination of 2 IDs

Tags: python, duplicates

I have a dataset like this:

```
ID1 ID2
11  22
11  34
22  35
35  9
41  10
52  87
9   65
34  43
```

I want an output dataset which detects duplicate IDs using ID1 and ID2 assignment as:

```
ID1   ID2     ID3
11     22     ID_11
11     34     ID_11
22     35     ID_11
35     9      ID_11
41     10     ID_10
52     87     ID_87
9      65     ID_11
34     43     ID_1
```

Since IDs `11,22,35,9,34` are all referring to one another, they are mapped to a single ID say ID_11

Comment: have you made an attempt; if so, can you put your (pseudo)code in?

Comment: A tuple can be used as an id or key in a set, dictionary etc. Use them.

Comment: ok. I create tuples out of them ((11,22),(11,34),....(34,33)). But how to detect duplication

Comment: It sounds like you want to build [disjoint sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't give too much information to write this cleanly, but this code should hopefully give you the python expressions you need to solve your problems, after changing some details.

```
# your id list, as a list of lists
vars = [
  [11, 22],
  [11, 34],
  [22, 35], 
  [35, 9],  
  [41, 10],
  [52, 87],
  [9, 65],
  [34, 43]
]

# create disjoint sets
groups = []
for id_1, id_2 in vars:
  for group in groups:
    if id_1 in group or id_2 in group:
      group.add(id_1)
      group.add(id_2)
      break
  else:
    groups.append({id_1, id_2})

# map the sets to some unique id/string/whatever
id_mappings = {}
for id_counter, group in enumerate(groups):
  id_mappings[id_counter] = group

# add the unique id/string/whatever to the initial list
for id_pair in vars:
  for group_id, group in id_mappings.items():
    if id_pair[0] in group:
      id_pair.append(group_id)

for var in vars:
  print(var)
>> [11, 22, 0]
>> [11, 34, 0]
>> [22, 35, 0]
>> [35, 9, 0]
>> [41, 10, 1]
>> [52, 87, 2]
>> [9, 65, 0]
>> [34, 43, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks. How is the disjoint logic working? "create disjoint sets"

Comment: in `groups`, i collect the disjoint sets. They are actual python sets, which can only hold one instance of any value you put in. If `id_1` or `id_2` can be found in one of the sets I have already created, add both to that set and `break` out of the inner loop, skipping the `else` statement. If no group was found (for example in the very first round), enter the `else` statement and create a new group, starting with the two ids we are currently looking at.